# Перехват std потоков из другого процесса (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Есть некое *консольное приложение* со стандартными потоками ввода и вывода через *эту же консоль*. Как мне заполучить потоки stdin/stdout *этого процесса* уже в своей программе? В какую сторону копать? Возможен также вариант с запуском *дочернего процесса* с помощью функции CreateProcess(...).

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY. Зачем вам понадобились заполучить эти потоки?

Comment: А перенаправления (пайпы) типа |, >, < в командной строке не годятся?